# Mongoose DB - Find inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following data inside a mongoose collection:

```
{
  map: 'Sydney',
  Postcode: 2000,
  mapItems: [
    {
      team: 'NONE',
      teamIcon: 20,
      x: 0.6092914,
      y: 0.28168318,
      flags: 0
    },
    {
      team: 'Alpha',
      teamIcon: 33,
      x: 0.63026464,
      y: 0.41642973,
      flags: 0
    },
    {
      team: 'Bravo',
      teamIcon: 20,
      x: 0.63026464,
      y: 0.41642973,
      flags: 0
    },
    {
      team: 'Alpha',
      teamIcon: 20,
      x: 0.63026464,
      y: 0.41642973,
      flags: 0
    }

}
```

I'm trying to return just the mapItems that have the team as "Alpha" and teamIcon is 33 or 52.

```
dyDB
    .find({
      $or: [
        {
          "mapItems.teamIcon": 33,
        },
        {
          "mapItems.teamIcon": 52,
        },
      ],
      $and: [
        {
          "mapItems.teamId": "Alpha" },
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((data) => {
      for (const dyn of data) {
        console.log(dyn);
      }
    });
```

But it just returns everything and doesn't seem to filter it. I'm not sure what else to try. Can anyone give some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `or` inside `and`:

```
dyDB.find({
    mapItems: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $and: [
          { $or: [{ teamIcon: 52 }, { teamIcon: 33 }] },
          { team: "Alpha" },
        ],
      },
    },
  })
  .then((data) => {
    for (const dyn of data) {
      console.log(dyn);
    }
  });
```

Comment: It is still returning everything, nothing is being filtered.

Comment: @Yesman, dot operator removed, can you check now

Comment: Now I am getting MongoServerError: unknown operator: $and

Comment: @Yesman, i fixed syntax, can you try now

Comment: "TypeError: conditional $and requires an array" is now coming up

Comment: Added **elemMatch** to search inside array